# Populate combo box in datagridview for new rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have this code which i am using to populate a combo box in a `datagridview`

```
Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(2)
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem2")
```

it works fine but when a new row is added to the `datagridview` the combo box is not popuated with the data - i want it to be populated with the same data for every row

Comment: you need to write more about your setup - how you add rows, what is the data source, etc.

Comment: You populate only cell in first row. Use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and `DataSource` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the selections to an individual `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` (which would be *only* for that specific cell), assign the selections to the entire `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` instead. Doing this will mean every cell in the column will share the same selection options.

```
With DirectCast(DataGridView2.Columns(2), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    .Items.Add("comboitem1")
    .Items.Add("comboitem2")
End With
```

Note that I am assuming column `2` is your combo box column since that is what is used in your snippet.

Comment: If column is predefined(created in the designer), then column can be used by generating variable `Me.MyDataGridViewComboBoxColumn` - without converting and index hardcoding

Comment: what needs to be added before the .Add ?

Comment: @charlie - The portion above uses a `With` block, the `.Add` is appended to what is defined in the `With` statement.

Comment: its saying " '.Add' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn' "

Comment: @charlie - It should have been `.Items.Add` - my mistake. I have updated the answer.